Repaired a leak in the main water supply, but it's leaking again. How do I make the repair permanent?
4 years ago, I repaired a water leak in the supply line to our house. My guess is the house (built in 1986) had settled and put pressure on the supply line coming into our basement, which made it split. The PVC from the street (bottom) and the copper into our house (top) were so badly misaligned when I dug it up and cut it for the repair that I had to put in this weird jog of PVC. I used primer and cement, and teflon tape on the connection to the copper. There were no leaks, so I buried it.

Well now there is a sound of flowing water from the supply line just inside the house, and a spinning water meter when the main valve inside the house is turned off, indicating once again a leak between the meter and our house. I assume it's going to be at this same spot.
When I dig it up and confirm that's the problem, what can I do differently to make sure I'm not doing this again in another 4 years? Thanks!

You need to confirm the problem before we can give you a solution.

I've determined the leak, it's coming from the seam where the PVC is connected to the copper on the threaded connection, near the top of the picture. Apparently that part of the connection was forced downwards, because there's a fan spray pattern coming from the bottom of the connection.  I don't know if I didn't brace it well enough, or the house just settled some more and put stress on the connection. I am wondering whether using pex instead of pvc would allow for more movement in the future.

You have a lot of glue on that repair and it weakens it. Shifting and pressure on the pipe from roots causes splits and ruptures.
Many plumbers in my area use flexible schedule 40 pipe. when repairing water lines in sandy soil and/ or with many roots. It holds up better when forced to move under the ground. Also glues up just like regular PVC pipe.

It looks like you fixed the misalignment.
However while digging you hurt the pipe and now has a chip.
You can see it at the top of the picture (pipe) on the left.
